# Making Rails routing beautiful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following in my Rails routes.rb:

```
  resource :sign_up, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :users
  get 'users/activate/:token' => 'users#activate', as: 'activate_user'
```

Which gives me the following routes:

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
      sign_up POST   /sign_up(.:format)               sign_ups#create
  new_sign_up GET    /sign_up/new(.:format)           sign_ups#new
        users GET    /users(.:format)                 users#index
              POST   /users(.:format)                 users#create
     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)             users#new
    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)        users#edit
         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)             users#show
              PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)             users#update
              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)             users#update
              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)             users#destroy
activate_user GET    /users/activate/:token(.:format) users#activate
```

I'd like to get rid of the `get 'users/activate/:token' ...` route and use nesting or scoping instead, though I can't figure it out. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a collection route for users:

```rb
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'activate/:token', :action => :activate, :as => :activate
  end
end
```

And it will give you routes like this:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
activate_users GET    /users/activate/:token(.:format) users#activate
         users GET    /users(.:format)                 users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)                 users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)             users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)        users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)             users#show
               PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)             users#update
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)             users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)             users#destroy
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Domon. Any idea how to use a `member` block without the id? The goal is `activate_user` instead of `activate_users` for the named route.